# Recommend me a good gaming mouse?

Tags: mice

Budget $200. Well, $50 to $200.

What should I buy?

I want it to be bluetooth mouse.

It must have left thumb button.

What would be great? The best? Several?

Wireless. By bluetooth is better so I do not need to plug another stuff.

I want to play overwatch. Basically I need the thumb button for quick melee attack.

Additional buttons are fine though I am not sure about the use. Maybe the more buttons the merrier. Maybe not.

Touch screen like apple's mouse is great. I want wheel for easy scrolling. But if the wheel is replaced by something like touch screen it'll be even better.

This seems to be a start.

Comment: What are your more detailed requirements? What types of games do you want to play? How long should the battery last? Should it support custom macros? Should it have (customizable?) lightning effects?

Comment: You have described your minimum standard to encompass the majority of bluetooth mouses made today. Your question will draw nothing but opinion. You should either make your question a great deal more specific or do some more personal research.

Comment: I want to be more specific but I do not know where to start.

Comment: For example, is left button better or worse? How many buttons should a good gaming mouse have? Etc.

Comment: @JimThio How about this - tell us what game titles you will be playing with this mouse - list as many as you can. Tell us about what mouse you are replacing, if any, and why it doesn't work for you. Finally, tell us if there are any dealbreakers like sizes, colors, or designs that are just not acceptable to you. That will help us really narrow down the field and get a lot more objective with our answers.

Comment: Overwatch. The one I am using now is a red mouse by logitech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the **[Logitech - MX Master Wireless Laser Mouse](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/logitech-mx-master-wireless-laser-mouse-black/4106015.p?id=1219621556487&ref=199&loc=8BacdVP0GFs&acampID=1&siteID=8BacdVP0GFs-SWOiOt0giGlgLWzpN4uMRQ)**. It's got a good bluetooth-based connection technology that is dead simple to use, it has a thumb button, and it enjoys a decent DPI for twitch shooting like Overwatch. I would actually recommend not getting too crazy with the buttons for games like Overwatch, because you don't want to be accidentally setting off ultimates or things like that in hectic situations.

Comment: Is this the same mouse with this http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/mx-anywhere2

Comment: does the middle button work?